# COUNT() doesn't work with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY column
```

I get the total number of rows from table, not the number of rows after GROUP BY. Why?

Comment: Works for me. What is the actual query?

Comment: @CL. did it work for you with sqlite?

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood the description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that is how `group by` works.  It returns one row for each identified group of rows in the source data.  In this case, it will give the count for each of those groups.

To get what you want:

```
select count(distinct column)
from table;
```

EDIT:

As a slight note, if `column` can be `NULL`, then the real equivalent is:

```
select (count(distinct column) +
        max(case when column is null then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), column
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```