Get 0 count resultset conditionally when used with group by clause and IN operator
I have 2 queries that gives me 2 different output even though performs same operation.
Query1 :
SELECT  fa.maintenance_request_id,
        count(fa.id) AS row_count 
FROM file_associations fa      
JOIN files f on (f.id = fa.file_id and f.cid = fa.cid) 
WHERE fa.cid = 12345 
  AND       fa.maintenance_request_id IN (17312470) 
  AND       fa.deleted_by IS NULL 
  AND       fa.deleted_on IS NULL 
GROUP BY fa.maintenance_request_id

Result: No result found
Query 2 :
SELECT COUNT(1) AS row_count 
FROM file_associations fa      
JOIN files f ON (f.id = fa.file_id and f.cid = fa.cid) 
WHERE fa.cid = 12345 
  AND fa.maintenance_request_id = 17312470 
  AND fa.deleted_by IS NULL 
  AND fa.deleted_on IS NULL

Result : row_count = 0
Is there any way to get row_count as 0 using 1st query? As in first query there is possibility that we get multiple maintenance_request_ids with 0 count.
I tried by removing group by clause in 1st query then but then it failed for desired result.
Expected result as : from 1st query if we have row_count as 0 then it should be returned as 0 rather than no result found.

The reason is you are using count using group by.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699602/count-doesnt-work-with-group-by

your problem is easier to solve if you format your queries. I formatted your queries for you.

No thanks, just upvote my comment :-)   But did we both edit at the same time? Did a GROUP BY disappear in query 2?

The [INNER] JOIN you're using only returns anchor set rows (i.e. from "file_associations") where both the anchor table and join table have matching records.  Since there are no matching records on the "files" table, this collapses the anchor set and returns an empty recordset, rather than simply appending the count.
To fix this, use LEFT JOIN, which will preserve the anchor set while also allowing you to aggregate (any) joined records.
SELECT  fa.maintenance_request_id,
    count(fa.id) AS row_count 
FROM file_associations fa      
    LEFT JOIN files f on (f.id = fa.file_id and f.cid = fa.cid) 
WHERE fa.cid = 12345 
  AND       fa.maintenance_request_id IN (17312470) 
  AND       fa.deleted_by IS NULL 
  AND       fa.deleted_on IS NULL 
GROUP BY fa.maintenance_request_id

Given that your WHERE conditions only use columns on "file_associations", you could also accomplish this by subquery:
SELECT  fa.maintenance_request_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) FROM files f WHERE f.id=fa.file_id AND f.cid=fa.cid) AS row_count
FROM file_associations fa
WHERE fa.cid = 12345 
  AND       fa.maintenance_request_id IN (17312470) 
  AND       fa.deleted_by IS NULL 
  AND       fa.deleted_on IS NULL

Note that if f.id is the primary key or constrained to be unique, can just use COUNT(1) here instead.
